# Method to align object local axis with global plane when rotating on local axis?

Tags: modeling, workflow, coordinates

[image: cube]

For the cube shown I want to do a rotation on the cubes local z axis so that the cubes local x axis lies on the global xz plane.

Comment: Try to apply rotation on the cube (CTRL+A)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Leon. I found a way to get the desired rotation using a LockedTrack constraint. The trick is to target an object that is 90 degrees to the plane you want to align to. Then apply visual transform.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the cube, <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> > **Cursor to Selected**, choose *3D Cursor* as current pivot point, or simply press <kbd>.</kbd> (the period key).
2. Press <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>, add a plane object, press <kbd>F6</kbd> then toggle *Align to View*, in order to make it parallel to global XZ plane.
3. Select the cube, then **View** > **Align View** > **Align View to Active** > **Top** (or simply press <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>), then add another plane object, toggle *Align to View* in <kbd>F6</kbd> panel, as well.
4. Keep current View unchanged, add an empty object, toggle *Align to View* in <kbd>F6</kbd> panel, as well. <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> to move a certain distance along its local X axis.
5. Add a **Boolean** modifier to either one of the plane, set Boolean mode to *Intersect*, choose another plane as the target object, in order to generate the intersection line from two planes.
6. Enable **Snap** icon on 3D View header, choose *Edge* as snap element, and *Active* as snap target, first select the cube, then select the empty by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> to make it active, <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd>, move mouse over the intersection line generated in Step 3, until it is snapped, <kbd>LMB</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm. Finally, delete these extra objects.

Comment: This is the non-coding way I've ever found so far, which is not hard, just need a bit more operations. I'll try make a GIF if necessary.